# Drag and drop local file in browser with Robot Framework

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, robotframework

I have a web application with some place holders for photos.  The only possibility to move a picture in a placeholder is to do a drag and drop from the filesystem. That means to open a Windows explorer and do a drag and drop of a photo from there into my Firefox browser. 
I have already included the AutoIt-library in my Robot Framework. But I do not find any way, how I could test this drag and drop scenario.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, It is not possible to drag and drop files from your local. While you are executing script your web driver scope will be up to web page which is displayed to you.

Try something else by using javascript executor. It may be useful for your scenario.